# Woocommerce: Show only products on offer on independent page

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

I want to create an independent page called "discounts" and show all the products on offer, I have the following function added to my son theme but it makes the main page of the store (with all products) show only products on offer, as I can have This function but only on a specific page? It occurs to me to perform an "empty" search to show all discounted products (using this function), am I going the right way?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'onsale_custom' );

function onsale_custom( $q ){

    $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();

    $q->set( 'post__in', $product_ids_on_sale );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a way to distinguish between the different pages,

What I've done to solve this issue was to create a new empty product category under the slug `discounts` (slug name can be changed, but keep track of it).

Then I've modified the function you attached to check if this category is being watched, via the [`is_product_category`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product_category.html) while providing the category slug name when calling this function.

Then settings the `post__in` query arg and **un-setting** the `product_category` to allow all products that are on-sale to be viewed.

This is the result:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'onsale_custom' );
function onsale_custom( $query ){
        if ( is_product_category('discounts') ) { // My slug name is 'discounts'
            $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
            $query->set( 'post__in', $product_ids_on_sale );
            unset ($query->query_vars['product_cat']);
        }
}
```